# Sorting a sparse matrix so that non-empty rows place on top

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sorting

I have a $n$ by $2$ matrix that has binary values(0,1) as its entry. For example

`m={{1,Null},{Null,0},{Null,Null},{0,0},{1,0},{0,1}}`

I want it to be sorted according to a simple rule: 1) place non-empty ones at the top and empty ones at the bottom; 2) if a row has only one non-empty value, the row that has a non-empty value in column 2 places before the row that has a non-empty value in column 1. For example, `{Null,0}` should be placed before `{1,Null}`.

So, the final list I want to have should look like:

`m_sorted={{0,0},{1,0},{0,1},{Null,0},{1,Null},{Null,Null}}`.

How can I do this type of sorting?

Comment: "`{Null, 0}` should be placed before `{1, Null}`" - and yet in your sorted list, you have `{1, Null}, {Null, 0}`. Do make up your mind.

Comment: @J.M. Oh, sorry:) I've fixed it.

Comment: Tip not directly directed at the problem here: if $n$ tends to be large in your use cases, then using `Null` is going to slow things down compared to using another integer, say, -1. The reason is that Mathematica can "pack" arrays that only contain one type (typically ints or floats). Using `Null` prevents that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very elegant but should do the trick:

- select the pairs of integers without reordering
- select the pairs of one integer and one `Null` and reorder by `Null` first
- select the pairs of `Null`s
- join all that

and enjoy.

```
   process[m_] := Block[{a, b, c},
      a = Select[m, IntegerQ@Total@# &];
      b = SortBy[Last]@Select[m, Count[#, Null] == 1 &];
      c = Select[m, # == {Null, Null} &];
      Flatten[Join[{a, b, c}], 1]]
    process[m]

    (* {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {Null, 0}, {1, Null}, {Null, Null}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the accept but, especially if you are looking for performances, Roman and kglr's answer are probably better.

Answer (score 4):

```
SortBy[m, {Count[#, Null], #[[2]]} &]

(*    {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {Null, 0}, {1, Null}, {Null, Null}}    *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SortBy[{Count[Null], Last}] @ m
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {Null, 0}, {1, Null}, {Null, Null}}
> ```

Also

```
m[[Ordering[Through[{Count[Null], Last}@#] & /@ m]]]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {Null, 0}, {1, Null}, {Null, Null}}
> ```